# Cross-platform file-sharing over wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, file-sharing, cross-platform

My iPhone has a program called Discover that creates a local website that allows me to share files from my phone over wifi and upload files. I have quite a limited download cap, so keeping the traffic within the network is important. I was wondering if there were any cross-platform programs (Mac, Linux, Windows) that allow me to share files between computers in a similar method so that I can avoid the hassle of complicated configuration.

Comment: do you need something like "look, these 100 files i have, feel free to grab" or is "i will now send you a file" enough?

Comment: "I will send you a file now"

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is. Samba or smb for short is the native file and printer sharing protocol on Windows and you can install a samba client and/or a samba server on a Linux system or Mac.

Here you can find info for [Mac's](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1568).

Setting up Samba on Linux will vary based on distribution. [Here](http://www.iamjacksdesign.com/blog/a-decent-samba-tutorial-for-ubuntu/) is one.

Some windows 7 and XP details [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/).

The [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29) article is also interesting.

Comment: I managed to get Samba set up. It requires a bit of configuration though, unlike Discover which just runs and tells you the IP address to type in

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cloud based file storage like [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) to share files. It is available on all common platforms and smartphones.

Comment: "over wifi" .. and most likely "traffic stays inside the lan"...

Comment: @Akira: Yes, I would like the traffic to stay within the network. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

[Opera Unite](http://unite.opera.com/application/132/) has a file sharing feature and since Opera runs on all platforms listed, this should have you covered.

Take note that you are basically running a web server on your computer when you do this, so secure your machine accordingly. The [guide](http://unite.opera.com/guide/) is a good overview.

Comment: Will the Opera Unite traffic go over the web or stay within the network?

Answer (score 0):

[Air Sharing](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing) ($2.99 on [Apple Store](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=289943355&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6)) :

> - Mount your iPhone or iPod touch as a Wi-Fi drive on your computer (Mac,
>     Windows, or Linux) or connect from
>     your computer's web browser.
> - Drag-drop files between your iPhone or iPod touch and your computers.
> - View and email documents in many common formats.
> - Send email attachments

Comment: Thanks. I just clarified the question, though, to make it clear that I am trying to share files between computers

Comment: With this program one can mount the iPhone as a drive on any computer and then share it (or any other directory) via Samba. There is no need for a cross-platform product, since Samba on Linux/Mac uses the Windows SMB protocol to share directories between Linux/Mac/Windows. No software is needed on Windows, since SMB is built-in.